# Visual Studio 2010 + Doxygen = Netbeans like comment autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, netbeans, autocomplete, comments, doxygen

Netbeans has this neat feature for java/phpdoc in which you type `/**` above the method, press enter and it generates a comment stub with the respective fields like

```
/**
 * <description>
 * @param foo
 * @param bar
 * @return 
 */
int asd(int foo, int bar){ }
```

Is there some plugin that does this on Visual Studio 2010 with Doxygen comments?